# Can't count number of instances of specific property in JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

My JSON is being returned by an ajax request and is stored in the `data` variable.

The JSON looks like this (the top line is a postcode / zip code and is different for every request):

```
  {
      "ML1 4EQ":{
          "ExchangeCode":"WSMOT",
          "ExchangeName":"MOTHERWELL",
          "Options":{
              "10":{
                  "Preference":"3rd Party Tail (TTB)",
                  "Supplier 1":9591,
                  "Supplier 2":3581,
                  "Wholesale":5200,
                  "RRP":6500
              },
```

and so on for other 9 more `Options`.

```
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to count the number of `Options` being returned but everything I've tried from reading other questions doesn't seem to work from returning undefined, to it only returning `3` instead of `10` (think I was counting the wrong level).

These include

```
var key, results = 0;
for (var k in data) { // only simple cross browser way to get the first property
    var obj = data[k];
    for (key in obj) {
        results++;
        count = results;
    }
    return; // no need to go further, we have counted the options in the postcode object
}
```

Comment: Please show at least one of the things you tried, so we can tell you where you went wrong instead of just giving you the answer.

Comment: @Barmar - question updated

Comment: Why don't you just make `Options` an array? Then you can count simply by doing `data.Options.length`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will count the total number of options inside the first object.

```
var count = 0;
for(var key in data){
  for(var i in data[key].Options){
    count++;   
  }
  break;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HYfrq/)

Answer (score 1):

Counting the number of properties in an `Object` isn't wholly straightforward. There isn't a property that will directly tell you, and if you `for...in` over them to count them you also get inherited properties, so if anyone's defined anything on `Object.prototype` you'll get the wrong answer.

In ECMAScript Fifth Edition you get `getOwnPropertyNames` which returns an array of non-inherited property names:

```
var options= {'1': 'a', '2': 'b'};
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(options).length; // 2
```

For browsers that don't support Fifth Edition yet (primarily IE<=8) you can shim it:

```
if (!('getOwnPropertyNames' in Object)) {
    Object.getOwnPropertyNames= function(o) {
        var names= [];
        for (var k in o)
            if (Object.hasOwnProperty(k))
                names.push(k);
        return names;
    };
}
```

However, if you have control over the format of the JSON output, I would strongly suggest turning your `Options` Object into a plain Array, which would seems to model your data much better. With an Array you can simply use `Options.length`.